# Filter and Sort a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-filter, array-splice

I'm building an image gallery and want to throw some promo banners in at random points to promote certain offers to users. Given the following array comes from a database query:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [insertDate] => 2014-11-10 11:22:58
                [keyword] => standard
                [mediaClass] => image
                [mediaURL] => http://image1.jpg
                [promoURL] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [insertDate] => 2014-11-10 11:23:08
                [keyword] => promo
                [mediaClass] => image
                [mediaURL] => http://image2.jpg
                [promoURL] => http://www.google.com
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [insertDate] => 2014-11-10 11:23:18
                [keyword] => standard
                [mediaClass] => image
                [mediaURL] => http://image3.jpg
                [promoURL] => 
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [insertDate] => 2014-11-10 11:23:28
                [keyword] => standard
                [mediaClass] => image
                [mediaURL] => http://image4.jpg
                [promoURL] => 
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [insertDate] => 2014-07-08 11:23:38
                [keyword] => promo
                [mediaClass] => image
                [mediaURL] => http://image5.jpg
                [promoURL] => http://www.google.com
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [insertDate] => 2014-07-08 11:23:48
                [keyword] => standard
                [mediaClass] => image
                [mediaURL] => http://image6.jpg
                [promoURL] => 
            )
     )
```

I am trying to do two things;

1)

Ensure there is only one **promo** image per **5 standard** images (in this example there are 2 so one would need to be removed/filtered from the array using the keyword key). This is to avoid spamming the user with too many promotional banners.

2)

Ramdomise the position of any images with the **promo** keyword but still maintain the order of images with the **standard** keyword by insertDate.

Bearing in mind the size of these result sets will always differ, what would be the best way to programmatically achieve this?

edit: I created the following function to tackle the first part:

```
function limitMediaPromos($array, $key, $value, $limit)
{
    // count the number of promo images
    if($count = $this->countElementsWithValue($array, $key, $value))
    {
        // find the avg number of promos per media set
        $avg = floor((count($array) / $count));

        // remove promo element if avg is over set limit
        if($avg > $limit)
        {
            $array = $this->removeElementWithValue($array, $key, $value);
        }
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Comment: nice requirements, where are you trials?

Comment: Hi Ghost, check the edit, this code works so far then I need to order by the insertDate value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better performance sort on the database side, and remove the mediaSort function and the usort($medias, 'mediaSort'); below.

```
function isMedia($var)  {
    return empty($var['promoURL']);
}

function isPromo($var)
{
    return !empty($var['promoURL']);
}

function mediaSort($mediaOne, $mediaTwo)
{
    return (strtotime($mediaOne['insertDate']) <= strtotime($mediaTwo['insertDate']));
}

function getImages($input)
{
    // Get the promos. O(n).
    $promos = array_filter($input, "isPromo");
    // randomize them. O(n).
    shuffle($promos);

    // Get the medias. O(n)
    $medias = array_filter($input, "isMedia");
    // Sort them (ideally sort it on the database side and skip this step). O(n log n)
    usort($medias, 'mediaSort');

    $promoOdds = 1/5;
    $promoGap = 5;
    $returnIndex = 0;

    $return = array();
    foreach ($medias as $media) {
        if (is_null($lastPromoIndex)
            || $returnIndex > $lastPromoIndex + $promoGap
        ) {
            if (rand(1,1/$promoOdds) == 1) {
                $return[] = array_pop($promos);
                $lastPromoIndex = $returnIndex;
            }
        }
        $return[] = $media;
        $returnIndex++;
    }

    if (is_null($lastPromoIndex)
        || $returnIndex > $lastPromoIndex + $promoGap
    ) {
        $return[] = array_pop($promos);
    }

    return $return;
}

print_r(getImages($input));
```

Comment: Thanks Nali, this was a really good answer. However, the requirements changed which are related to a different question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854492/merge-array-into-established-array-at-random-indexes-in-php